# Should variables be reused to optimize resource utilization?

Tags: c#, memory-management, global-variables

I am Using Microsoft Visual C# 2010. I have several methods that use a large bitmap for local processing, and each method can be called several times.
I can declare a global variable and reuse it:

```
Bitmap workPic, editPic;
...
void Method1() {
    workPic = new Bitmap(editPic);
    ...
}
void Method2() {
    workPic = new Bitmap(editPic.Width * 2, editPic.Height * 2);
    ...
}
```

or declare a local variable in each method:

```
Bitmap editPic;
...
void Method1() {
    Bitmap workPic = new Bitmap(editPic);
    ...
}
void Method2() {
    Bitmap workPic = new Bitmap(editPic.Width * 2, editPic.Height * 2);
    ...
}
```

The second way is better for code clarity (local variables for local use). Is there a difference in terms of resource utilization?

Comment: There are several optimizations possible if you re-use variables. The most interesting one is probably to reduce the number of dynamic memory allocations. (Java re-wrote part of the swing API for that reason, allowing somewhat anti-paradigmatical in-out parameters). But that problem surfaces with many small allocations, not with the probably few (big) allocations here. Plus: In your example the bitmaps are allocated anew in either case, anyway; you are only re-using references. To change the scope of the mere *reference* to a bitmap makes no difference; auto variables don't cost anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to keep the memory allocated to you can use `workPic` again after the method, you should register it as class variable. If not, you can free memory (always a good idea) by letting it go out of scope.

Allocating one variable doesn't matter much to the framework which manages memory. Only if you recreate a variable inside a tight loop you may benefit by reusing the variable. If you have basic types, you even reuse the same memory. Else, only the reference to the allocated memory is kept, so not that much benefit you have from there.

Note it is very important to `Dispose` your `workPic` since now you have a memory leak in the unmanaged memory behind `Bitmap`. Preferably use `using`.

Answer (score 3):

> **Why Global Variables Should Be Avoided When Unnecessary**
>
> **Non-locality** -- Source code is easiest to understand when the scope of its individual elements are limited. Global variables can be
>   read or modified by any part of the program, making it difficult to
>   remember or reason about every possible use.
>
> **No Access Control or Constraint Checking** -- A global variable can be get or set by any part of the program, and any rules regarding its
>   use can be easily broken or forgotten. (In other words, get/set
>   accessors are generally preferable over direct data access, and this
>   is even more so for global data.) By extension, the lack of access
>   control greatly hinders achieving security in situations where you may
>   wish to run untrusted code (such as working with 3rd party plugins).
>
> **Implicit coupling** -- A program with many global variables often has tight couplings between some of those variables, and couplings
>   between variables and functions. Grouping coupled items into cohesive
>   units usually leads to better programs.
>
> **Concurrency issues** -- if globals can be accessed by multiple threads of execution, synchronization is necessary (and too-often
>   neglected). When dynamically linking modules with globals, the
>   composed system might not be thread-safe even if the two independent
>   modules tested in dozens of different contexts were safe.
>
> **Namespace pollution** -- Global names are available everywhere. You may unknowingly end up using a global when you think you are using a
>   local (by misspelling or forgetting to declare the local) or vice
>   versa. Also, if you ever have to link together modules that have the
>   same global variable names, if you are lucky, you will get linking
>   errors. If you are unlucky, the linker will simply treat all uses of
>   the same name as the same object.
>
> **Memory allocation issues** -- Some
>   environments have memory allocation schemes that make allocation of
>   globals tricky. This is especially true in languages where
>   "constructors" have side-effects other than allocation (because, in
>   that case, you can express unsafe situations where two globals
>   mutually depend on one another). Also, when dynamically linking
>   modules, it can be unclear whether different libraries have their own
>   instances of globals or whether the globals are shared.
>
> **Testing and Confinement** - source that utilizes globals is somewhat more difficult to test because one cannot readily set up a 'clean'
>   environment between runs. More generally, source that utilizes global
>   services of any sort (e.g. reading and writing files or databases)
>   that aren't explicitly provided to that source is difficult to test
>   for the same reason. For communicating systems, the ability to test
>   system invariants may require running more than one 'copy' of a system
>   simultaneously, which is greatly hindered by any use of shared
>   services - including global memory - that are not provided for sharing
>   as part of the test.

reference: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to understand here is that field and variable is only holding a reference, the memory will be allocated to the object(s) created by "new".
So in both cases all created bitmap objects need to go through garbage collection.

Difference is that object only referenced in method will be ready to be collected right after method execution, when the object which still have reference in a field will be ready to be collected only when the object containing the field also will be ready to be collected.

The only case when it make sense to introduce the field is when you have the same object reused through the life cycle of the host object.

In cases when you recreate object in the beginning of the method definitely variable is recommended.

Comment: Good clarification. One could perhaps emphasize that creating a local *reference* costs literally nothing. It wiil not even be implicitly initialized, e.g. zeroed. It's just that the stack pointer will be adjusted a little bit differently.